# how to change z position of an UIBezierPath() graph?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

i have coded multiple graphs with UIBezierPath(), and the last graph coded is over the others.

How do i change the "z position" of a graph when a button is pressed to place it over the others graphs?

Comment: Your question is too vague without more details. By default rendering in iOS is not 3D, so z position doesn't really make sense. You can get "2.5D" graphics with some tricks, where each layer is like a piece of paper that you can rotate in 3 dimensions, but normal iOS drawing does not do perspective rendering. For that you need to use OpenGL or Apple's Metal framework.

Comment: If you describe the effect you're after in more detail it's possible we can help you achieve it, or you might need to use OpenGL or metal to get true 3D rendering.